# a-frame: playing a youtube video on a plane

Tags: aframe

I have been trying to show a youtube video inside an a-frame entity. When I use the a-video tag it gives a CORS error.

```
<a-video src="https://youtube.com/..."></a-video>
```

I have tried the a-link but nothing seems to happen

```
<a-link src="https://youtube.com/..."><a-link>
```

I would like the user to click on the plane (wall) to play a video. Any suggestions on how this can be achieved.

Thanks

Raj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The official a-frame FAQ](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/introduction/faq.html#can-i-render-youtube-videos-as-a-texture) says this:

> No. You could [proxy YouTube videos](https://github.com/cvan/webvr360) as a texture or download them locally to serve, but that is against their terms of service.

Check out the the second link for a proof-of-concept.

I think they only want you to embed their videos via the iframe embed code you get when you right click a video on youtube and then hit "Copy embed code", and that would not work in aframe as far as I know.